# Change the order of sentences from a given textbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I though about resolution but i don't know how.

Example, i have some sentences in each line in textbox.

```
Sentence 1
Sentence 2
Sentence 3
```

And i want output "mixed/randomed" something like that:

```
Sentence 3
Sentence 1
Sentence 2
```

Any ideas? I'm not well into programming.

Comment: Yes, look into the String class; maybe String.Split. Then the Random class. Try some code and if you have a specific question, post your code and the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use Linq's [OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx) extention method to do the trick.

```
    'Setup
    Dim txtYourTextBox As New TextBox
    txtYourTextBox.Text = "Sentence 1" & ControlChars.NewLine & "Sentence 2" & ControlChars.NewLine & "Sentence 3"

    'Creates random numbers.
    Dim rnd As New System.Random()

    'Get the list of sentences randomized.
    Dim lstRandomizedSentences As List(Of String) = txtYourTextBox.Text.Split(ControlChars.NewLine).OrderBy(Function() rnd.Next).ToList()

    'Clear the textbox before repopulating with randomized sentences.
    txtYourTextBox.Text = String.Empty

    'Loop through all of your randomized sentences to populate the textbox.
    For Each strSentence In lstRandomizedSentences

        '.Trim() so extra line breaks aren't added.
        txtYourTextBox.Text += strSentence.Trim() & ControlChars.NewLine

    Next
```